# Android findViewbyId with a variant string

Tags: android

```
TextView textView1= (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

I d like to create something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
   TextView textView= (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView+i);
}
```

how can i do that?

Leslie

Answer (score 25, accepted):

See [`getIdentifier`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). Basically, you want something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
   int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("textView" + i, "id", getPackageName());
   TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(resId);
}
```