# Convert a string to a resource Uri for mp3 playback

Tags: java, android

I am trying to play an mp3 using the Media player class. When I hardcode the mp3 resource it works, however I would like the resource to come from a string instead of directly accessing it like `R.raw.mp3name`.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String Choice= bundle.getString("bundledChoice");        
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("R.raw." + Choice);        
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(activity.this, myUri);
mPlayer.start();
```

If I change the second to last line to `mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(activity.this, R.raw.song)` it will work, the problem is creating the resource URI dynamically from the string which is obtained from the bundle.

Please advise.

Comment: i suppose a better way of putting it is "How do I reference a Resource @ R.raw... using a string"

Comment: Resource at R.raw is made at the compilation of the R class which creates the IDs for the resources. The URI.parse() requires 
an RFC 2396-compliant, encoded URI PARAMETER.  R.raw.song is the int ID of this song. You might want to read something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559902/android-how-can-i-convert-android-net-uri-object-to-java-net-uri-object and check how to make a Uri from a File object. Thanks

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004713/get-content-uri-from-file-path-in-android

Comment: Thanks Sergey, I used this post to get the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679434/android-findviewbyid-with-a-variant-string

Comment: @brux, Sorry I'm being dim here, could you post a code fragment? I can't quite make the link between the post you refer to and solving the problem ...

Comment: @brux, Ahh, sorted it, I've put another answer up, interested to see if it's what you meant ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I am using to this little challenge is based on @Creator's answer to this post: [Android - getting an image resource into Uri: IllegalArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730210/android-getting-an-image-resource-into-uri-illegalargumentexception).

The solution is to use

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://[package]/[res type]/[res name]");
```

[package] you either know (com.company.blah.superdooperthing), or can be determined using getPackageName().

[res type] is (I think, and it seems to work) the directory inside "res" that you are pulling the resource from. So, for an audio file .../res/raw/nicemusic.mp3, res would be "raw".

[res name] is (I think, and it seems to work) the file name (less extension) of the resouce. So, for the example above, it would be "nicemusic".

So, a more systematic approach might be:

```
String dataResourceDirectory = "raw";
String dataResoruceFilename = "nicemusic";

Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + 
                  dataResourceDirectory + "/" + dataResoruceFilename);
```

Better solutions welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to do it this way?

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(path+"/"+fileName);
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744683/sound-file-as-variable-in-android-mediaplayer?lq=1) which is very simple and works (for me), where everything I tried with Uri.parse() did not work.

```
private void playMp3(String nameOfFile){
    MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier(nameOfFile, "raw", getPackageName()));
    mPlayer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer can be found here. Resolving the int ID of the resource helps: [Android findViewbyId with a variant string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679434/android-findviewbyid-with-a-variant-string)

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to do it to turn the literal string`R.raw.xyz` into a URI.
What you really want is to first resolve `R.war.xyz` into a string and then turn that into an Uri.
There is e.g. `Context.getString()` for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String choice= blabla// your solution to get song name
    String debug = "R.raw." + choice;   
    Uri myUri = Uri.parse(debug);        
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(activity.this, myUri);
    mPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Just refactoring out R.raw... into a variable will not help here.