# Playing a local video on Glass

Tags: android, google-glass

I'm trying to play a local video (mp4) on Google Glass using VIDEOPLAYER.

My code is:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("com.google.glass.action.VIDEOPLAYER");
i.putExtra("video_url", "android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.close_upper_case_mp4); 
startActivity(i);
```

When I launch the code (on "startActivity(i)"), I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.launchInBackground(DebugUIPlugin.java:1257)
at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.launch(DebugUITools.java:757)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.debugRunningApp(AndroidLaunchController.java:176)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.clientChanged(AndroidLaunchController.java:1742)
at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.clientChanged(AndroidDebugBridge.java:912)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.update(Device.java:600)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.update(Client.java:903)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleWait.handleWAIT(HandleWait.java:88)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleWait.handleChunk(HandleWait.java:66)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.callHandler(MonitorThread.java:414)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:322)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

and it seems like the Glass is loading something but nothing happens.

I think that the path is not correct, because I tried other things (like MediaPlayer) and I get the same result.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue. com.google.glass.action.VIDEOPLAYER does not access local resources of the project. you can solve this by using video view or place your video on the external storage directory of the glass.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9742053/1837158) answer, you have to set the path like this:

```
"android.resource://[package]/[res type]/[res name]"
```

so it would be

```
"android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/raw/" + R.raw.close_upper_case_mp4
```

It may also be that the path is not properly encoded, try

```
Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/raw/" + R.raw.close_upper_case_mp4).toString();
```

(with or without the "/raw" part)

Comment: It seems that adding the "/raw/" doesn't change anything.

Comment: I added the code mentioned in the link:
int test = this.getResources().getIdentifier("close_upper_case_mp4", "raw", this.getPackageName());
        if (test != 0) 
        {
            result = true;
        }
and "test" was not 0, do I have no idea what is the issue here.