# Android ID and ImageView

Tags: java, android

I am making an Android app of Checkers based on XML widget (like imageview).
I made a table of 8X8 of imageviews and call their id like so (i00 , i01 etc).
I have  two questions:

1. I've tried to make a reference of the imageviews in the code like this:

   ```
   ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.i00);
   ```

   and it gives me an error:

   ```
   "i00 cannot be resolved or is not a field"
   ```
2. Is there any way of getting id by a string?
   For example I have a imageview which id is i01, can I get it by:

   ```
   String str = "i01"
   ```

   and then give `str` as a parameter for some kind of method?

Comment: Project>Clean and try again (if you're using Eclipse as your dev enviro).

Comment: look at `getIdentifier` in `Resource` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: That call is correct, check this thread which talks further about that error:
 [“id cannot be resolved or is not a field” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296047/id-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field-error)

2: Something like this should work:

```
String str = "i02";
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(str, "id", getPackageName());
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(id);
```

Check this link for more information [findViewById with String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179797/how-to-do-a-findviewbyid-r-id-stringvarhere)

Comment: Cool, could you clarify your second problem? I don't think I quite understood it.

Comment: my second quesion is if there is a way to call an id insted of findViewById , if i want to use a string that contain the name of the id. like String str ="i02" and then findViewById(R.id.str)

Comment: @nivik try that and see if it works. Also if this answer has been helpful, consider upvoting/accepting it as the answer.

Comment: what superclass do i need to use this getResources() method?

Comment: You would need a Context.